# Regex expression to find strings between two strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write a regular expression which returns a string which is between two other strings. For example: I want to get the string along with spaces which resides between the strings "15/08/2017" and "$610,000"

```
a='172 211 342    15/08/2017  TRANSFER OF LAND   $610,000        CASH & MTGE'
```

should return

```
"TRANSFER OF LAND"
```

Here is the expression I have pieced together so far:

```
re.search(r'15/08/2017(.*?)$610,000', a).group(1)
```

It doesn't return any matches. I think it is because we also need to consider spaces in the expression. Is there a way to find strings between two strings ignoring the spaces?

Comment: It is because you need to escape `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Regex `Lookbehind & Lookahead`

**Ex:**

```
import re

a='172 211 342 15/08/2017 TRANSFER OF LAND $610,000 CASH & MTGE'
print(re.search(r"(?<=15/08/2017).*?(?=\$610,000)", a).group())
```

**Output:**

```
 TRANSFER OF LAND
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.search(r'15/08/2017(.*)\$610,000',a).group(1)
'  TRANSFER OF LAND   '
```

Since `$` is a regex metacharacter (standing for the end of a logical line), you need to escape it to use as a literal `'$'`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to use `find`:

```
a = '172 211 342 15/08/2017 TRANSFER OF LAND $610,000 CASH & MTGE'
b = '15/08/2017'
c = '$610,000'

a[a.find(b) + len(b):a.find(c)].strip()
```

> 'TRANSFER OF LAND'